# Probability with Exp distribution, CDF, and multiple variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

You have a list of chores to do at home, but are expecting family to arrive shortly. The amount of time until their arrival (measured in hours) can be modeled as an Exp(2) random variable. Your list of chores contain 4 activities, each of which take 15 minutes to complete. Let X be the (whole) number of chores you complete before your family arrives. Find the CDF of X.

So I set Y~Exp(2) = time until family's arrival and X as the number of chores done. I'm not really sure how to proceed from there?

Answer (score 1):

**Outline:** The notation $\text{Exp}(2)$ is somewhat ambiguous. The exponential with density function $\lambda e^{-\lambda y}$, for $y\gt 0$, is sometimes described as being $\text{Exp}(\lambda)$ and sometimes described as being $\text{Exp}(1/\lambda)$. (Note that $1/\lambda$ is the mean.)  I do not know what notation your course/book uses. So I will use $\lambda$, which could either be $2$ or $1/2$.

The tasks each take $1/4$ of an hour. The probability that $X=0$ is the probability the arrival time is $\lt \frac{1}{4}$. This is $1-e^{-\lambda/4}$.

The probability that $X=1$ is the probability that the arrival time is between $1/4$ and $1/2$. This is $e^{-\lambda/4}-e^{-2\lambda/4}$.

The probabilities that $X=2$, $X=3$, and $X=4$ are calculated in a similar way.

Now that you have the probabilities, the cumulative distribution can be found.

Comment: So do I add them for the CDF (i.e. 0<=X<1 instead of X=0)?

Comment: Let $p_0, p_1,p_2,p_3,p_4$ be the probabilities that $X=0,1,2,3,4$. For the cumulative distribution function $F(x)$, which I am surprised they are asking for, we have $F(x)=0$ if $x\lt 0$, $F(x)=p_0$ for $0\le x\lt 1$, $F(x)=p_0+p_1$ for $1\le x\lt 2$, $F(x)=p_0+p_1+p_2$ for $2\le x\lt 3$, similarly for $3\le x\lt 4$, and $1$ for $x\ge 4$.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help so far. But one more question, how did you get e^(−λ/4)−e^(−2λ/4)?

Comment: We get one task finished if the waiting time is $\lt 1/2$ (hours) but $\ge 1/4$. The probability of this is $\Pr(Y\lt1/2)-\Pr(Y\lt 1/4)$. This is $(1-e^{-2\lambda/4})-(1-e^{-\lambda/4})$, which simplifies.

Comment: From what I understand FX(x) = 1 - e^(−λx), so I'm confused about the variables? If x = 1, then it'll be λ(1) not, λ(1/4) and λ(1/2)?

Comment: One task takes $15$ minutes, or, since we are measuring time in hours, $1/4$ of an hour. So we will get $1$ task completed if the guests come in more than $1/4$ hour, but less than $2/4$ of an hour. The probability that $Y$, the waiting time, is $\le y$ is $1-e^{-\lambda y}$. So the probability they arrive in less than $1/4$ of an hour ($0$ tasks done) is $1-e^{-\lambda/4}$. Similar calculations apply to other numbers of tasks finished.